# bash script or Python to parse gradle dependencies

Tags: android, python, bash, shell, gradle

I am looking to write a bash script to parse through a gradle build file and generate a list of what dependencies it has in it.
I also need to account for dependency version numbers being variables (that are defined in the root level gradle file.

Any suggestions on how I can go about this would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

example gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  ....
}

dependencies {

  compile "com.android.support:design:$support"
  compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support"
  compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:$mixpanel"
  compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$playServices"
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
}
```

example output:

```
com.android.support:design:25.3.1
com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1
com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.8.7
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2
io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0
```

Comment: there is the `sed` command, which is awful but works, depending on how you want to solve this problem, i personally would create a little python script to call it with an arg.

Comment: i've thought about using python (and would prefer it) but this will be running on a jenkins server that I am not totally sure will have python.  So I was thinking of using a bash script to be safe.

Comment: Python comes pre-installed on most Linux distributions,

Comment: hmm that's true.. I will look into this sed command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel?

Use gradle:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies [--configuration implementation]
```

and you get the tree which can be far more complex than what you can extract with a script.

Comment: can i export this to a txt file?  My end goal is to have a text file like my example output

Comment: To export to text file `./gradlew app:dependencies --configuration compile | tee file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
support="25.3.1"
mixpanel="4.8.7"
playServices="11.0.2"

results=$(grep compile input.txt | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '"' | tr -d "'")
eval echo $results | sed 's/ /\n/g'
```

- The awk removes the compile word
- The first tr removes the "
- The second tr removes the '
- The eval replaces the variables bye their values
- The sed replaces the spaces between each line by \n

Comment: this will give me the the proper output... but the variable definitions will not be within the same file.  they will be in the gradle file in the root directory

Comment: Pass them as arguments to this script then.  Somehow the values you want will have to make it into this script.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you simply use the dependency generator shipped by gradle.
If you have gradlewrapper, simply use this

```
./gradlew :allDeps > oputput.txt
```